# Bot Emualor "ExceptionMessage": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.", "exceptionType": "System.NullReferenceException",

Tags: azure-sql-database, botframework

I want to store the conversation on the chat bot and am using `IActivityLogger` for it.
The code is as follows :

```
public class EntityFrameworkActivityLogger : IActivityLogger
{
    Task IActivityLogger.LogAsync(IActivity activity)
    {
        IMessageActivity msg = activity.AsMessageActivity();
        using (BotApplicationSqlData.ConversationDataContext dataContext = new BotApplicationSqlData.ConversationDataContext())
        {
            var newActivity = Mapper.Map<IMessageActivity, BotApplicationSqlData.Activity>(msg);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newActivity.Id))
                newActivity.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            dataContext.Activities.Add(newActivity);
            dataContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I am getting an error of Request to

> 'https://botapplicationsqlexample.azurewebsites.net/api/messages' failed: [500] Internal Server Error .

On debugging, it shows a `Null Reference Exception` and `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

The conversation is getting stored on the Azure DB but no reply from the Bot's end is coming. Can anyone please help with me this?

Comment: When debugging, what object is null?  What line is throwing the null reference exception?

Answer (score 1):

I ran this code, and noticed that if an activity of type `ActivityTypes.Typing` comes through, `activity.AsMessageActivity()` returns a null object.  To fix this, just surround the saving code with a null check:

```
    public async Task LogAsync(IActivity activity)
    {
        IMessageActivity msg = activity.AsMessageActivity();

        if (msg != null)
        {
            using (Data.ConversationDataContext dataContext = new Data.ConversationDataContext())
            {
                var newActivity = Mapper.Map<IMessageActivity, Data.Activity>(msg);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newActivity.Id))
                    newActivity.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                dataContext.Activities.Add(newActivity);
                dataContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried it and republished my code on Azure but the same error still persists.